# Ionic 4 POST to PHP backend

Tags: php, android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to POST data to a PHP backend and receive back the values and push it into an array. Hence, I created a function to do just that. However, I'm not to change the API on the backend (written in PHP). So I cannot change it to suit my normal methods of using POST.

This is my function

```
test() {
    let data = "method=getThis" + "&db=myDatabase"
    this.http.post("API URL", data).subscribe(data => {
      this.result = data;   // get data in result variable
      this.items = JSON.stringify(this.result); // then convert data to json string
      // console.log(this.items);
      this.allData = JSON.parse(this.items); // parse json data and pass json string
      // console.log(this.allData.length); // got result of particular string
      this.array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.allData.length; i++) {
        this.array.push({
          data1: this.allData[i].data1,
          data2: this.allData[i].data2,
        })
      }
      console.log(this.array[0])
    })
  }
```

And this is an example function on the backend

```
else if($_POST['method']=="getThis"){
    global $conn;
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $_POST['db']);
    $name="";
    $result=array();
    $r=mysqli_query($conn,"select data1,data2 from table");
    while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        array_push($result,$rs);
    }
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
}
```

So how do I actually get it to post? I'm stuck here. I usually post with JSON and then decode the JSON on the backend. But this time around I'm not developing the backend and not changing it so gotta use the one provided.

Posting using POSTMAN with this

```
method=getThis&db=myDatabase
```

works well. Not sending JSON just a text. So how do I actually achieve this in Ionic.

Comment: this.allData = "method=getThis&db=myDatabase" would be a quick but lazy way that would probably work.

Comment: @JohnV. hahahaha.. unfortunately it did not work..

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. It looks like the result will be an object with a "result" key and that will be an array. You should try this.allData = data.result

Answer (score 0):

You could try it that way. It works for me:

First import:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators/map";
```

Your function:

```
test() {
    let data = "method=getThis" + "&db=myDatabase"
    this.http.post("API URL", data).pipe(
      map(res => res.json())
    ).subscribe(response => {
      //Here your code
      // 'response' is json
    });
  }
```

Comment: res.json() will not work in ionic 3 and 4.. (as far i tried).. if im not mistaken its because it returns a json by default so no need to use res.json again.. anyways, what version of ionic are you running on??

Comment: I am using 4.1.1 and it works for me. Here a pice of code what is perfectly working in 4.1.1: ```    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/sql/get/", data).pipe(
      map(res => res.json())

    ).subscribe(response => {
      console.log("GET DATA FROM SQL:");
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response[4].Name);
      
      //this.loginField = response[4].Name;
      //this.passwordField = response[4].Password;
      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you are sending is in plain text, you will need to add a header mentioning the content type.
`import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

```
const httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'text/html'
    })
};

this.http.post("API URL", data, httpOptions).subscribe()
```

Comment: this.http 

from where I did get this (http)

Comment: That will have to be imported into the specific file as such`import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`


Then, add it to the constructor as such `constructor ( public http: HttpClient )`

Answer (score 0):

PHP side should be return JSON and told browser content type is application/json, please test your code base on one simple page.

```
//demo.php
<?php
$data = ['message' => 'Hello world.'];
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

//If allow cross domain and not configration in Ngix/Apache
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept-Encoding, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Authenticationtoken");

echo json_encode($data);
```

And please try http access demo.php again.